# Can't start linux , boot linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot, multi-boot, grub2

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      32,3kB  73,6GB  73,6GB  primary   ntfs            boot
2      73,6GB  162GB   88,1GB  extended                  lba
5      73,6GB  108GB   34,0GB  logical   ntfs
6      108GB   109GB   1023MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
7      109GB   162GB   53,0GB  logical   ext4
3      162GB   439GB   277GB   primary   ntfs
4      439GB   500GB   61,2GB  primary   ntfs
```

sda1 => Windows XP
sda4 => Windows 7
sda7 => Linux

---

I have 3 operating systems loaded onto one computer: Windows XP, Windows 7 and Linux Mint 15 Olivia.  After I installed linux Mint, I could not start Windows 7 nor Windows XP, but could only boot to linux Mint.

When opening Windows 7 falls error: A disk read occurred error.CTRL+ALT+DEL restart. How to solve? With the help grub?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879622/cant-boot-windows-7-not-starting

I was able to restore my Windows boot loader with help from this article http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/. Since this fix restored the Windows boot loader, it overwrote Grub2, and I can no longer boot to Linux Mint.

How do I reload Grub, so that it will boot both to Windows and to Linux?

Comment: Please can you tell us which linux distribution you are using, and your grub configuration file?

Comment: Linux Mint 15 Olivia

Comment: Boot to linux with a CD/USB.  Most distributions will boot to a live desktop, from there you can mount your linux partition and get at your grub2 config files.  Reinstalling grub into your mba will be trickier.

Comment: can fix this problem with Visual BCD Editor ?

Comment: You have TeamViewer ?

Comment: Well, I guess you could do it with BCDedit; I have never done it that way.  I have always used grub2.  I'm sorry, I will not remote onto your computer.

Comment: Just use grub2 and install it to MBR. You can easily configure it to chainboot windows partitions. BCD will break too often.

Answer (score 0):

Why sorry for the 2 years late reply. In this case it would probably have been best to try to boot from a Linux Mint live cd and reinstall grub from there.

Grub is still installed properly, so regardless of distro, if you can boot into a live CD and are wondering how to fix this from a command line, the command to fix it would look something like this:

```
grub2-install /dev/sda
```

If the command completes without error and installs grub to your MBR, then next boot you should boot straight into grub again. Sometimes variations of the command are needed, for example on Arch Linux the command would look like this:

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sda
```

Depending on circumstances you may need to chroot into your existing linux installation from a live cd to successfully run the command.